# Calculating availPhysical for an Item using locationID and siteID as filters in place of values

Tags: axapta

How can I calculate availPhysical for user entered filter ranges instead of single LocationID/SiteIDs? ItemId being a concrete value.

eg.

- Site 'GREEN,BLUE'
- Location '1*'
- Item 'XYZ0001'

I have this working by using a query to loop through locations and use InventOnhand with dimension parameters to grab availPhysical on each pass. This however is very slow, and impractical for displaying on the SalesLine. I think I may need to add a modified version of findSum in the InventSum table?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the `InventSum` and `InventDim` summing on the field `AvailPhysical`.

Using X++:

```
while select sum(AvailPhysical) from inventSum
    where inventSum.ItemId == 'XYZ0001'
    exists join inventDim
    where inventDim.InventDimId == inventSum.InventDimId &&
         (inventDim.Site == 'GREEN' || inventDim.Site == 'BLUE') &&
          inventDim.Location like '1*'
{
    ...
}
```

You should probably use a query instead.